# How to prevent WP query searching in executed shortcodes

Tags: wp-query, shortcode

I am trying to figure out why the shortcodes are executed.

My search module looks for a search query in posts via WP_Query.

The problem is that in my posts, there is an elementor widget showing a nav for all the different categories. So when i try to gather the posts that are relevant, it gathers all the posts because they all contain that nav. This widget being stored as a shortcode, i don't understand why it is executed while doing the WP Query, i tried setting suppress_filters to true, but it's the same.